# Jquery use variable to .show() div

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to use .show() to display div elements like slides in a slide show.

What I would like to do is use the ID property of a button on my nav bar to cause that slide to "slide in" much like a slide show.  So button one has an id of "1".  I then use Jquery to append "#slide" to that id and get "#slide1".  which corresponds to a specific slide that I wish to show.  So far I have been unable to get the "slide" div to appear with $variable.show().

Am I going about this wrong?

This is what I have so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/greyoxide/RN2jC/

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    $(".slide").hide();
    var content = $(this).attr('id');
    var fix = "'" + '#slide' + content + "'";
    $("#show").val(fix);
    $(fix).show();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the single quotes `'`, so change:

```
var fix = "'" + '#slide' + content + "'"; // This translates to "'#slide1'"
```

To:

```
var fix = '#slide' + content; // This translates to "#slide1"
```

End result:

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    $(".slide").hide();
    var content = $(this).attr('id');
    var fix = '#slide' + content;
    $("#show").val("'" + fix + "'"); // If you still want to display single quotes
    $(fix).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RN2jC/9/

Comment: Thanks for the help and examples.  I guess I thoght I needed the quotes in order to call it in variable form.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the quotes around the slide ID.

```
$(".button").click(function () {
  $(".slide").hide();
  var content = $(this).attr('id');
  var fix = '#slide' + content;
  $("#show").val(fix);
  $(fix).show();
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zaknotzak/RN2jC/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the apostraphe in your `fix` string:

`var fix = "'" + '#slide' + content + "'";`

Should be:

`var fix ='#slide' + content;`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you put quotes before and after `fix`? That's just wrong, otherwise it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/RN2jC/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    $(".slide").hide();
    $("#slide"+$(this).attr('id')).show();
});
```

[jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RN2jC/8/)

Comment: This far more elegant than my original idea.  Thanks.